# exec other program and connect to it with unix domain

Tags: linux, sockets

i exec a server program(it is a socket server, unix domain), and connect to it.
maybe the server is starting, so connect awalys fail with errno is ENOENT.

i have 
    setsockopt(m_socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &timeout, len);
it still fails.

does anybody know a good solution.
thanks.

Comment: Please show some code. And what exactly are you trying to do and what are your observations. Your description is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool KRpcSelectThread::connectToServer(const string &port, timeval    timeout)
{
int ret;

if ((m_socketfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    return false; 

socklen_t len;
timeval oldtimeout;
if (getsockopt(m_socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &oldtimeout, &len) < 0 || len < 0)
    oldtimeout = timeout;

len = sizeof(timeout);
setsockopt(m_socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &timeout, len);
//int flag = 1; 
//setsockopt(m_socketfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *) &flag, sizeof(int));

struct sockaddr_un server_addr; 
bzero(&server_addr,sizeof(server_addr));

server_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strncpy(server_addr.sun_path, port.c_str(), strlen(port.c_str()));

socklen_t server_addr_length = sizeof(server_addr);
ret = ::connect(m_socketfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, server_addr_length);
if (ret < 0)
{
    int er = errno;
    return false;
}
```

steps:
1. fork and exec another server program(listen unix domain)
2. run this function connectToServer
 maybe server is starting(before listen), so it cause connect failed ?